# Web plugin like uWebKit for Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

uWebKit plugin doesn't support Android.

Anyone knows a similar plugin that supports Android? (in addition to iOS and standalone)

Comment: I think [UniWebView](http://uniwebview.onevcat.com) would be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but this option is open source https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

Comment: We actually already tried this one, but got DLL issues and could not manage to use it :(